# Converting a string from scraped javascript into a python dictionary

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to crawl the product description of the product in the link below.

[image]

I tried to crawl by using **selenium**, but the information is protected by the website so all the information I get by **selenium** is the same with **requests**. So to make to script run faster, I crawl it by using **requests**.

Below is the code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

res= requests.get("https://www.real.de/product/345246038/")
soup=BS(res.text,'lxml')
code=soup.prettify()
split =  code.split("attributes:")
for value in split:
    after=value.split(",condition$:b")
    for value in after:
        if "{default:[{name:" in value:
            clean = value.replace(",highlighted:void 0}}","}").replace(": None","")
```

Here is the string in the variable **clean** :

[image]

I convert the clean into a dictionary :

```
import yaml
d = yaml.load(clean)
```

But it is not properly formatted like a dictionary : because not all the words are in the double quote ( "" )

So I use regrex to extract only the word in the string that are not in double quote. Here is the code :

```
r = re.compile(r'[{,:][a-zA-z]+[:}]', flags=re.I | re.X)
string = r.findall(clean)  
ta=[]          
for w in string :
    m = re.search('[a-zA-z]+', w)
    if m:
        new = str('"')+m.group(0)+str('"')
        ta.append(new)
```

However. I don't know how to put the words which are in the double quote ("") inside the **clean** variable again.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the text as JSON?

Comment: I tried : import json
data = json.loads(clean) . But it throw error : JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Comment: Yeah, `json` won't parse a JavaScript object in string form like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `(?!")` that mean match character that not followed by quote

```
if "{default:[{name:" in value:
    clean = value.replace(",highlighted:void 0}}","}").replace(": None","")
    # add the lines below
    clean = re.sub(r'(\{|,)(?!")(\w+?):', r'\1"\2":', clean)
    clean = re.sub(r':(?!")(\w+?)(\}|,)', r':"\1"\2', clean)
    jsonData = json.loads(clean)
    print(json.dumps(jsonData, indent=2))
```

Comment: you're welcome, please mark the answer as correct.